# Firestore Custom Tokens

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to use a custom auth token with firestore. I am using nodejs to generate the token with the following code.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var uid = "some-uid";
var claim = {
  control: true
};
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, true)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    console.log(customToken)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

When I run it I get a token. I take that token and try it out using
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/example-project-5caa9/databases/(default)/documents/users with the headers

Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjbGFpbXMiOnsiY29udHJvbCI6dHJ1ZX0sInVpZCI6InNvbWUtdWlkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI4MTQ0NzY3LCJleHAiOjE1MjgxNDgzNjcsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2dvb2dsZS5pZGVudGl0eS5pZGVudGl0eXRvb2xraXQudjEuSWRlbnRpdHlUb29sa2l0IiwiaXNzIjoiZmlyZWJhc2UtYWRtaW5zZGsteG9jMDRAZXhhbXBsZS1wcm9qZWN0LTVjYWE5LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZmlyZWJhc2UtYWRtaW5zZGsteG9jMDRAZXhhbXBsZS1wcm9qZWN0LTVjYWE5LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIn0.Bjl6VY5CZKIpNyCayROWr_ZBSRmo11hiwtnx_cbbw2Ggk3J2x0Ml2OkpXhU-vAD6Q53fCZwGgXeCdxnsXw0lr55cJH3Q6J7gitzQoRnfJgUX9Dv1gbI90OWashxMmxtzPIpwgSnfBv61mkdv9ZVrF8o362mQBx_LUQzvGgVPEN9_9UNCH7peOS4KYr_YRMpCQVem0XMNh9WKlyBZuScjHpY6dZZhXqOHda0W9-MNAfvQ-D0pt-osq4ty-D_WYk6CjLNmxzvHoZeoIk1YShJM4Mpyec3lXFcCXNYG2c3_r2tskTB0LF7Fc7Bg5XuJwlrAzHrnRis6iZFCx8sqH1b-Zg

get the following JSON.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

My rules are as follow

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly how you're invoking the REST API using the token you received.

Comment: OK, I fixed the post.

Comment: Certainly you're writing code to make this HTTP request, right?  Can you show that code?

Comment: I haven't implemented it but right now I am using postman to test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly access REST APIs with a custom token. You need to sign in using the custom token, and obtain an ID token. There are 2 ways to do this:

- [Sign in from a Firebase Client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients)
- [Use the Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) to exchange the custom token to an ID token.

Then you can access the Firestore REST API with the resulting ID token:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#working_with_firebase_id_tokens

Comment: do I really need to use ServiceAccountKey.json and firebase-admin sdk to generate custom token?

Comment: Maybe usefull: copied from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens. "You can create a custom token with the Firebase Admin SDK, or you can use a third-party JWT library if your server is written in a language which Firebase does not natively support."