# firebase MISSING_CUSTOM_TOKEN error while curl "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Goal: I want to learn how use custom tokens with FireStore.

Tentative: I try follow [firebase curl example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) by

```
curl "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=AIzaSyCO0B7UXo2OcfhXQ2gBxHAPuN5muusiIFw" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"token":"123456","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

and I got

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "MISSING_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "MISSING_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

The curl command above was filled in with my "Firebase Web API Key" copied from Firebase/My Project/General/Web Api Key. Then I added a token just for testing "123456". If I understood correctly the documentation, I should get a Token back.

My final goal is to add a Custom Token to my Firebase project which allows an Angular client connect to Firestore and be notified when the document is changed.

For creating a Custon Token, the best steps I have found is [Stackoverflow Custom Token Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687648/firestore-custom-tokens). So I am trying to create it with:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./angular-firebase-auth0-3c084-firebase-adminsdk-lu97a-6ba2ba41e0.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var uid = "some-uid";
var claim = {
  control: true
};
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, true)
  .then(function (customToken) {
    console.log(customToken)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

angular-firebase-auth0-3c084-firebase-adminsdk-lu97a-6ba2ba41e0.json was downlowaded from Firebase and contains:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "angular-firebase-auth0-3c084",
  "private_key_id": "6ba2ba41e0bf3837841aa9772c7d880b7ce3be81",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAg ...... +n+uYQTJSJPM7Tvgfssa8X1KK09zoj2f7ZLvcjGzl/VF2D7uf23VtAL2RZsB7z14\ny4rnDCc4Rx7nslGUk6kwEz+xJYUpP96rkp5iv/qUuoveJdI/NogJjgUtvRUa2evA\ntg2PV9xsYvkt8+8Ce79fYKA=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-lu97a@angular-firebase-auth0-3c084.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "114324662014690107039",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-lu97a%40angular-firebase-auth0-3c084.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

and I got

```
C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token>node server
C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-generator.js:205
            throw new error_1.FirebaseAuthError(error_1.AuthClientErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, errorMessage);
            ^

FirebaseAuthError: `developerClaims` argument must be a valid, non-null object containing the developer claims.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:147:16)
    at FirebaseTokenGenerator.createCustomToken (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\auth\token-generator.js:205:19)
    at Auth.BaseAuth.createCustomToken (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\auth\auth.js:94:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\server.js:12:14)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)[39m {
  errorInfo: {
    code: [32m'auth/argument-error'[39m,
    message: [32m'`developerClaims` argument must be a valid, non-null object containing the developer claims.'[39m
  },
  codePrefix: [32m'auth'[39m
}
```

So, my main question is: what I am missing to create a Custom Token with curl above? Since is a Custom Token, at least for a Hello World, I can use a very simple Token like "123456", right?

A secondary question, in above server.js, am I providing the right file expected in admin.credential.cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understating of Firebase Custom Token Auth, you cannot send a plain unencrypted token like that. In order for that to work, you would have to generate the token based on a uid, which could be the `123456` by using the same code you were already have:

```
const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken("123456")
```

Then use that customToken to make the test request of the curl command.

To your secondary question, the injection of the service account  on the `admin.credential.cert()` command is correct and if you compare the actual `.json` file to the sample provided on the official [Cloud IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), everything seems correct.

The only thing that could cause issues is if your `private_key`, `private_key_id` or any other of the fields that need to be replaced are wrong, but that would be something that only you can check.

Hope this helps you.