# FirebaseAuthError: `developerClaims` argument must be a valid, non-null object containing the developer claims

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Final Goal: create a simple NodeJs to provide a Firestore Custom Token.

Current tentative: I am trying exactly this approach [Custom Token Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50687648/4148175). According to this question Author he is able to get the Custom Token. Unfortunatelly I keep getting

```
C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token>node server
C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-generator.js:205
            throw new error_1.FirebaseAuthError(error_1.AuthClientErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, errorMessage);
            ^

FirebaseAuthError: `developerClaims` argument must be a valid, non-null object containing the developer claims.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:147:16)
    at FirebaseTokenGenerator.createCustomToken (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\auth\token-generator.js:205:19)
    at Auth.BaseAuth.createCustomToken (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\node_modules\[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\auth\auth.js:94:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\firestore-custom-token\server.js:32:14)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)[39m {
  errorInfo: {
    code: [32m'auth/argument-error'[39m,
    message: [32m'`developerClaims` argument must be a valid, non-null object containing the developer claims.'[39m
  },
  codePrefix: [32m'auth'[39m
}
```

All NodeJs files are:

server.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "angular-firebase-auth0-3c084",
  "private_key_id": "6ba2ba41e0bf3837841aa9772c7d880b7ce3be81",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEv ... deleted ... 2PV9xsYvkt8+8Ce79fYKA=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-lu97a@angular-firebase-auth0-3c084.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "114324662014690107039",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-lu97a%40angular-firebase-auth0-3c084.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

 admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(exports.serviceAccount)
});

var uid = "NSBFu2YJNDgLQJCZ99dRJlP4DRo2"; //copied from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firetestjimis/authentication/users
var claim = {
  control: true
};
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, true)
  .then(function (customToken) {
    console.log(customToken)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "firebase-auth0-nodeserver",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Node.js server to provide custom auth token.",
  "repository": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "author": "Auth0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

In case it adds something, I managed to deploy a Cloud Function that returns a Custom Token with bellow typescript. Nevertheless, I need same approach in our local Servers.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const getCustomToken = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    if (admin.apps.length < 1) {   //Checks if app already initialized
        admin.initializeApp();
    }
    const uid = "NSBFu2YJNDgLQJCZ99dRJlP4DRo2"; 

    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
        .then(function (customToken) {
            console.log(customToken.toString);
            response.send(customToken);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        });
});
```

*** edited 
Thanks to Frank's answer I fix this issue by "... admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid).then... ".

Nevertheless, the generated Custom Token seems useless (or maybe I udnerstood something wrong).

The desire is to have a token that allowm me to post a document to Firestore. Well, with Cloud Function above I get a Token then I post it to googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken which returns an idToken that I can use to post a document to Firestore collection. I understood the NodeJs server above would generate a token with same characteristics as the one I generated from above Cloud Function but it seems I got wrong the point.

Basically, I am trying https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690299/4148175 and it seems the question Author got it working. Funny I can do it using Cloud Function but I get issue generating the Custom Token from above NodeJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have syntax problems like this, the docs are your friend. From the reference documentation for [`Auth.createCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#createcustomtoken):

> `createCustomToken(uid: string, developerClaims?: Object): Promise<string>`

...

> Parameters
>
> `uid: string`
> The uid to use as the custom token's subject.
>
> Optional `developerClaims: Object`
>
> Optional additional claims to include in the custom token's payload.

So the second argument to `createCustomToken` needs to be an object with the custom claims you want to add. My guess is that the boolean in the question you linked was a valid call in an older version of the SDK.

Comment: thanks. Now I can print a Custom Token to command line console. Nevertheless, when I try to use it I get   "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "CREDENTIAL_MISMATCH",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "CREDENTIAL_MISMATCH",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }. I mean, when I try to post the generate Custom Token to googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken I get CREDENTIAL_MISMATCH

Comment: That seems to be a different problem. It sounds like you're using credentials from a different project. But I recommend posting a new question if that doesn't seem to be the case/cause.

Comment: I just created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348847/googleapis-com-identitytoolkit-v3-relyingparty-verifycustomtoken-returning-crede